# Roslyn MsBuildWorkspace compilation emit does not contain my changes

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to do minor changes to documents with roslyn and then compile the project to a new dll. But when I compile it to a new dll all my changes are gone. Am I missing something here?

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(@"path\to\.csproj").Result;

var documents = project.DocumentIds;
foreach (var documentId in documents)
{
    var document = project.GetDocument(documentId);
    var root = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result

    var rewrite = new MyRewrite();
    root = rewrite.Visit(root);

    var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(root);
    var compilation = newDocument.Project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

    // When I look at the sementatic model here it contains my changes.
    var sementaticModel = 
    compilation.GetSemanticModel(newDocument.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result); 

    // But when I inspect this dll with dotPeek it's still the old code without changes.
    compilation.Emit("new/dll/path");   
}
```

Comment: Did you confirm that new root actually contains the modified nodes?

Comment: Yeah I inspected both the "newDocument" object and the syntax tree in the sementatic model.

Comment: Does `var sementaticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(newDocument.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result);` give the same result?

Comment: The getSemanticModel part gives me the updated code but the emit below gives me the old one. Thats why it so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it worked by changing:

```
var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(root);
```

to

```
var newDocument = document.WithText(root.GetText());
```